# android initialize database install once

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Im developing an app for Android and Im looking for a way to create a database table and initialize it but to do it only once when the app is installed or when its first time started. After the table is created and initialized for the first time I do not want this code to rune any more because it inserts a lot of data in to the table.
Haw can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Extend SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class MyDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

Context c;

public MyDB(Context c) {
    super(c, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.c=c;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+DB_TABLE+" ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "+COL_1+" text, "+COL_2+" text, "+COL_3+" text, "+COL_4+" integer, "+COL_5+" integer, "+COL_6+" text );");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int from, int to) {
    Log.i("onUpgrade", "From Version "+from+" to version "+to);
    switch(from) {
    case 0:
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS wine;");
        db.execSQL("create table "+DB_TABLE+" ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "+COL_1+" text, "+COL_2+" text, "+COL_3+" text, "+COL_4+" integer, "+COL_5+" integer, "+COL_6+" text );");
    case 1:
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+DB_TABLE+" ADD COLUMN "+COL_6+" text;"); //comment was not in the original database
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way, the database is only ever created and initialized once. And won't be recreated or reinitialized unless you increment the database version or change the database name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that is extends SQLLiteHelper and overwrite the onCreate() method to create your table and insert any rows. After this time, the database queries will not be executed unless you get a writable instance of it and pass in your own queries.

If you wanted to make changes to your app in the future, you would need to override the onUpgrade() method to make changes to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Check if database is empty on every start of your app, if so insert your data, otherwise ignore.